# 22.04 Bonding Confusion

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, network-bonding

I'm struggling with bonding.  I have a Cisco C220 and trying to create a bonding of my 2 of 3 ports (2x 10Gb SFP+ ports, and 1GB Ethernet ports). I have devices pointed to each of their IP addresses and I am setting up fault-tolerance for my 10Gb links to a bonded IP at 192.168.1.203. I am doing a netplan & NetworkManager control.  I've turned on `managed=true` in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`

My `00-installer-config.yaml` and `01-network-manager-all.yaml` are identical, well... because I'm throwing spaghetti at the wall and changes aren't being affected.  Here's the file contents...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp12s0:
      dhcp4: yes
    enp1s0f0:
      dhcp4: yes
    enp11s0:
      dhcp4: yes
  bonds:
    bond0:
      interfaces: [enp11s0, enp12s0]
      addresses: [192.168.1.203/24]
      routes:
       - to: default
         via: 192.168.1.254
      parameters:
        mode: balance-rr
        primary: enp11s0
        transmit-hash-policy: layer3+4
        mii-monitor-interval: 1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - "1.1.1.1"
          - "8.8.8.8"
```

I've run...`sudo modprobe bonding`
verified the bonding with `sudo lsmod | grep bonding`
then `sudo netplan apply`
and even tried `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`
and the bond will not come up.

Following a reboot my route table...

```
root@solarczar-UCSC-C220-M4S:/etc/netplan# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         dsldevice.attlo 0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp11s0
default         dsldevice.attlo 0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 enp1s0f0
default         dsldevice.attlo 0.0.0.0         UG    102    0        0 enp12s0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 br-25af4793f0bf
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-034c84b50ce3
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     425    0        0 br-034c84b50ce3
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-d28a65ac3b60
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     432    0        0 br-d28a65ac3b60
172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-e3aaad61e336
172.22.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-e73fd129b6e2
172.23.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-aafa86433ed6
172.23.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     431    0        0 br-aafa86433ed6
172.24.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-483ab991fc09
172.25.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-9b26775d9624
172.26.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-462e8ac3b66d
172.26.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     428    0        0 br-462e8ac3b66d
172.27.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-25af4793f0bf
172.28.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-2bd1f14da1c3
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp11s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 enp1s0f0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     102    0        0 enp12s0
```

I have even tried turning down the links, adding the bond manually, assigning the links to the master, and then turning up the bond.  The bond will show in ifconfig, but I can't send traffic to it and doesn't survive a reboot. I tried turning on `systemd` and `networkd` interfaces and unhashing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, and following a hard reset, I had no ethernet connectivity...assuming a conflict...so I turned all the systemd elements down and rehashed my `interfaces` file, did a `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` ...and low and behold it came up.  Yay!  see below....

```
solarczar@solarczar-UCSC-C220-M4S:~$ sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
solarczar@solarczar-UCSC-C220-M4S:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp11s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 16:82:5d:cf:95:82 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 00:c8:8b:16:97:9f
    inet 192.168.1.161/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp11s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp1s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 16:82:5d:cf:95:82 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr cc:46:d6:fc:78:bc
    inet 192.168.1.201/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp1s0f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: enp12s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 16:82:5d:cf:95:82 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 00:c8:8b:16:97:a0
    inet 192.168.1.202/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp12s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: enp1s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether cc:46:d6:fc:78:bd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: enp134s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:c8:8b:16:6a:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: enp135s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:c8:8b:16:6a:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: enx9cebe887681c: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9c:eb:e8:87:68:1c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 16:82:5d:cf:95:82 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.203/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1482:5dff:fecf:9582/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: br-034c84b50ce3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:92:52:fe:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-034c84b50ce3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:92ff:fe52:fec5/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: br-462e8ac3b66d: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:05:79:c8:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.26.0.1/16 brd 172.26.255.255 scope global br-462e8ac3b66d
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:5ff:fe79:c800/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: br-9b26775d9624: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:4b:e7:50:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.25.0.1/16 brd 172.25.255.255 scope global br-9b26775d9624
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: br-d28a65ac3b60: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:c9:60:1c:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.1/16 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global br-d28a65ac3b60
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:c9ff:fe60:1c95/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
14: br-e3aaad61e336: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:09:20:4e:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.21.0.1/16 brd 172.21.255.255 scope global br-e3aaad61e336
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
15: br-e73fd129b6e2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:12:9f:28:a7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.22.0.1/16 brd 172.22.255.255 scope global br-e73fd129b6e2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
16: br-25af4793f0bf: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:b5:e4:95:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.27.0.1/16 brd 172.27.255.255 scope global br-25af4793f0bf
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
17: br-2bd1f14da1c3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:45:a8:42:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.28.0.1/16 brd 172.28.255.255 scope global br-2bd1f14da1c3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
18: br-483ab991fc09: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:73:e7:38:45 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.24.0.1/16 brd 172.24.255.255 scope global br-483ab991fc09
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
19: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:7e:7c:76:f7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
20: br-aafa86433ed6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:33:18:44:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.23.0.1/16 brd 172.23.255.255 scope global br-aafa86433ed6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:33ff:fe18:4405/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
22: veth7bffbda@if21: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-d28a65ac3b60 state UP group default 
    link/ether 56:fc:6d:bb:41:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
    inet6 fe80::54fc:6dff:febb:415c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
24: vetha7b00c2@if23: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-aafa86433ed6 state UP group default 
    link/ether 92:66:ca:bf:61:94 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::9066:caff:febf:6194/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
26: vethdde6cd8@if25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-034c84b50ce3 state UP group default 
    link/ether 7a:9b:55:c8:d4:71 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::789b:55ff:fec8:d471/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
28: veth34bc713@if27: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-462e8ac3b66d state UP group default 
    link/ether de:6b:75:31:bb:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 3
    inet6 fe80::dc6b:75ff:fe31:bb4b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
30: vethe43897a@if29: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-aafa86433ed6 state UP group default 
    link/ether ca:c2:5c:ea:d7:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 4
    inet6 fe80::c8c2:5cff:feea:d724/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
32: veth0af69ab@if31: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-034c84b50ce3 state UP group default 
    link/ether 0a:f8:44:8b:eb:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 6
    inet6 fe80::8f8:44ff:fe8b:eb5f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
34: vethace271c@if33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-034c84b50ce3 state UP group default 
    link/ether d6:64:e2:58:13:5c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 5
    inet6 fe80::d464:e2ff:fe58:135c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
solarczar@solarczar-UCSC-C220-M4S:~$ 
solarczar@solarczar-UCSC-C220-M4S:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         dsldevice.attlo 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp12s0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp12s0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-034c84b50ce3
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     425    0        0 br-034c84b50ce3
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-d28a65ac3b60
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     432    0        0 br-d28a65ac3b60
172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-e3aaad61e336
172.22.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-e73fd129b6e2
172.23.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-aafa86433ed6
172.23.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     431    0        0 br-aafa86433ed6
172.24.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-483ab991fc09
172.25.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-9b26775d9624
172.26.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-462e8ac3b66d
172.26.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     428    0        0 br-462e8ac3b66d
172.27.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-25af4793f0bf
172.28.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-2bd1f14da1c3
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 bond0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp1s0f0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp12s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp11s0
```

Well, I couldn't leave well enough alone and because I wanted to see if it would survive a reboot.  So I rebooted, and it did not come back up.  Then I did another...

```
solarczar@solarczar-UCSC-C220-M4S:~$ sudo netplan apply
solarczar@solarczar-UCSC-C220-M4S:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         dsldevice.attlo 0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp11s0
default         dsldevice.attlo 0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 enp1s0f0
default         dsldevice.attlo 0.0.0.0         UG    102    0        0 enp12s0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 br-25af4793f0bf
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-034c84b50ce3
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     425    0        0 br-034c84b50ce3
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-d28a65ac3b60
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     432    0        0 br-d28a65ac3b60
172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-e3aaad61e336
172.22.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-e73fd129b6e2
172.23.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-aafa86433ed6
172.23.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     431    0        0 br-aafa86433ed6
172.24.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-483ab991fc09
172.25.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-9b26775d9624
172.26.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-462e8ac3b66d
172.26.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     428    0        0 br-462e8ac3b66d
172.27.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-25af4793f0bf
172.28.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-2bd1f14da1c3
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp11s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 enp1s0f0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     102    0        0 enp12s0
```

And it is not up!  Damn it!  I don't know what I did.  Did another `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` and it still would not come up.

I have been pecking away and reading for a week trying to figure it out with no joy and decided to stop and see if you guys could see something I'm missing.  Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You should set the `dhcp4: no` for both `enp12s0` and `enp11s0` as you could get conflicting or not needed IP addresses.

Comment: Just did.  No effect on implementing the bond.  Oh well, this feels like an Ubuntu bug somewhere. You follow the recipe and nothing happens.

Comment: I honestly wish that I knew Netplan better as they have deprecated the `ifupdown` in favor of it.  But, my networks still use the `ifupdown` and I have no issues with bonding and stuff.  Anyway, looking through the examples at https://netplan.io/examples it looks as though you can either not assign the NICs before the bond, or you can make them optional.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a very similar issue and I've been throwing similar bits of spaghetti at the wall, the one that stuck is very uncool - and this appears to have nothing to do with netplan per se,  because I had upgraded a box all the way from 16.04 and still have the old interface configs on it and yet bonding still did not work

Now, you do apparently still have to have ifenslave installed in order to make any of this work and some tutorials will tell you that the way to get netplan configs to override the configs in /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/network/interfaces.d is to remove ifupdown.  For me, that removed ifenslave, which made bonding not work.

I had thought that the fix was just to install ifenslave and I'm still a little unsure why it appears not to be the case.

However, what worked for me was

```
ifenslave --detach bond0 eth0
ifenslave bond0 eth0
```

then the machine functioned as advertised.

This is not a great solution, although I could add it to an rc.local script it leaves a very bad taste in my mouth.

This survives `netplan apply` and `systemctl restart networking` but does not survive something like `rmmod bonding` `modprobe bonding` followed by `netplan apply`.

I know this isn't a complete answer, more of a workaround, but I didn't want to ask another question because I think this is more or less the same issue

---

Today I found that simply running `ip link dev eth0 up` corrected the issue and made things work.

I believe we missed a step during upgrading that would have made this irrelevant.  `netplan migrate` appears to not be a command in 22.04, although the source code (migrade.py) still exists, there may be a way to run it, but I didn't have any luck.